# Java - Sending a String or paragraph via TCP

Tags: java, string, socket.io

I'm new to Java, and I'm learning how to send messages via the Socket() class.

I'm trying to wrap my brain around how strings are sent and received between 2 simple chat programs.  I've found plenty of examples online, for TCP/UDP chat clients and chat servers.

But I'm still confused with buffered data and strings.

In my code I added 3 fields (field1, field2, area), and a submit button with an event listener.
Below is part of the code, showing how I attached the listener and the class it instantiates.

```
......more code above this

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     new SendRequest();
   }
});


public class SendRequest{

  SendRequest(){

   try{

      String dip = field1.getText(); // ip address
      String port = field2.getText(); // port num
      int pnum = Integer.parseInt(port);
      String mess = area.getText(); // large text box
      Socket skt = new Socket(dip, pnum);

      /* kinda not sure about this part, with strings */


   }
   catch(IOException io){
      System.out.println("error? " + io.getMessage());
   }
  }
}
```

I've seen so many example online, that now I'm slightly more confused.

After instantiating the new Socket(), what's a decent way to send multi-line text?

Comment: What is unclear about this for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "kinda not sure part" create a PrintWriter using the OutputStream from the socket,
then to print the message call the PrintWriter's print method on the "mess" String from your text area.

This puts the message string in the output stream buffer but isn't sent till you call the PrintWriters flush method.

Finally close the PrintWriter.

The text should be sent multilined as the textareas string will have contain "\r\n" when you pressed enter.

Eg.

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream());
output.print(mess);
output.flush();
output.close();
```

Comment: This was the simplest that worked sending to a simple ServerSocket() on a different computer.

Answer (score 2):

Once the socket is connected and you obtain its output stream (via `socket.getOutputStream()`), writing to the socket is not at all different from writing into any output stream, such as a file. You should write your multi-line text in exactly the same way that you would write it into a file.

How to send multi-line text — it seems like the best way to go about it would be to construct an `ObjectOutputStream` on top of the socket's output stream, and use that. For example:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(...);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
```

And then write your object (a string, an array of strings, or a `List`, or whatnot):

```
oos.writeObject(mess);
```

As long as the class of `mess` is `Serializable` (and if `mess` is a collection of objects, and those objects are also `Serializable`), this will work. You can read the objects from the other end by using `ObjectInputStream` and `readObject`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to write data. For instance, I like serializing a Class and sending an an instance of that class via ObjectOutputStream. But since you are only sending a string, a BufferedWriter might be easier to handle.

Code:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(skt.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8")); //optional encoding
writer.write(mess+"\r\n");
```

It's not more confusing than that, the "\r\n" is there for easier handling of the last line at the receiving end.

Comment: I agree.  And this is exactly what I would do.  But I think Isaac's, more "object oriented" approach, also has merit.  IMHO...

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it involves customly adding line terminators (which are not portable across platforms, by the way). My take on it is that if I can avoid manipulating what I'm sending - I prefer doing so.

Comment: @Isaac To be fair /r/n does work on all common platforms. But I do agree that using an OOS is more elegant, even though there's the issue of sending objects to non-java applications which you can't do with an OOS. Either way, I think both methods are very important to understand.